# Set Retrofit Base URL from Strings.xml file located on res/values folder

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to set retrofit base URL from Strings.xml file. However, the service generator can't access the Context class in Android. Can anyone give any advice?

Here's the snapshot of my code

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .baseUrl("http://localhost/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient
                        ().create()));
```

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi request you to read question before marking duplicate. question about read value of string.xml without Context

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi it’s totally different question!

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way you can access any of the string resources is with a Context (i.e. an `Activity` or `Service`). What I've usually done in this case, is to simply require the caller to pass in the context.

**You can use only system resources only without Context:**

```
Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.somecommonstuff)
```

**try below solutions**

1. Create a subclass of `Application`, for instance public class App extends `Application` {
2. Set the android:name attribute of your `<application>` tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to point to your new class, e.g. `android:name=".App"`
3. In the `onCreate()` method of your app instance, save your `context` (e.g. this) to a static field named `mContext` and create a static method that returns this field, e.g. `getContext():`

This is how it should look:

```
public class App extends Application{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Now you can use: `App.getContext()` whenever you want to get a context, and then `getResources()` `(or App.getContext().getResources())`.

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .baseUrl(App.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING);)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().setLenient
                        ().create()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to add the Retrofit dependency in class which extends Application.

And in that case you can easily instantiate your retrofit object by setting the base url using the `getString()` method and storing the url in strings.xml file.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(getString(R.string.server_url))
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
```